# How to get class object from class name string in the same module?

Tags: python

I have a class

```
class Foo():
    def some_method():
        pass
```

And another class **in the same module**:

```
class Bar():
    def some_other_method():
        class_name = "Foo"
        # Can I access the class Foo above using the string "Foo"?
```

I want to be able to access the `Foo` class using the string "Foo".

I can do this if I'm in another module by using:

```
from project import foo_module
foo_class = getattr(foo_module, "Foo")
```

Can I do the same sort of thing in the same module?

The guys in [IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) suggested I use a mapping dict that maps string class names to the classes, but I don't want to do that if there's an easier way.

Comment: and yes, using a mapping dict is probably the proper way to go...

Comment: Thanks. I ended up refactoring 'cause I didn't want to use `globals` or use a mapping dict.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
import sys
getattr(sys.modules[__name__], "Foo")

# or 

globals()['Foo']
```

Comment: Accepted this answer 'cause it covers both `sys` and `globals` methods.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but while a good answer it could be further improved by mentioning the pros/cons of the two options and which option is considered more pythonic.

Answer (score 11):

[You can do it with help of the `sys` module:](http://ideone.com/XXlIzj)

```
import sys

def str2Class(str):
    return getattr(sys.modules[__name__], str)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
globals()[class_name]
```

Note that if this isn't strictly necessary, you may want to refactor your code to not use it.