# python peewee insert, with table name in variable

Tags: python, peewee

Most of time we'll use following way to create items with peewee:

`User.create(name='aa', age=20, ...)`

But in some circumstances the Table name is stored in a variable. I notice I can use `database.execute_sql()` to execute raw SQL statement. But I think it's a little messy.

Is there a way to do something like this?

`#{TableName}.create(name='aa', age=20, ...)`

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959996/get-python-class-object-from-class-name-string-in-the-same-module):

```
class Table(Model):
    text = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = DB

table_name = 'Table'
table = globals()[table_name].create(text='lorem ipsum')
```