# Changing column order of a bunch of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I want to order the columns of a bunch of dataframes to get a particular column first, thus

```py
for rr in [df1,df2,df3]:
    cols = ["Time"]+[col for col in rr if (col != "Time")]
    rr = rr[cols]
```

but this fails, apparently, because `rr` is a copy of each df, so the column order gets changed on `rr`, but it is not changing the order of the columns of `df1`, `df2`, etc.

Tricky...

Comment: initialize a blank list `l=[]` and append `l.append(rr)` after you do `rr = rr[cols]` ?

Comment: I found something similar in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536802/iterating-over-different-data-frames-using-an-iterator   Bascially create a dict with keys "df1", "df2" and "df3" and load those into the dict as eval(key)... and then an iteration over keys MyFrames[rr] = MyFrames[rr][cols]  will create new dataframes and I'll be able to find them later.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit]**

Following @Jon Clements clever comment, you could even do:

```py
for df in [df1,df2,df3]:
    df.insert(0, 'Time', df.pop('Time'))
```

---

**[Initial answer]**

You could do something like this:

```py
for df in [df1,df2,df3]:
    save = df['Time']
    df = df.drop(columns='Time')
    df.insert(0, 'Time', save)
```

Comment: Or just... `df.insert(0, 'Time', df.pop('Time'))` ?

Comment: Very nice. Thanks :-)