# Create instance of class from function

Tags: python

This is my first question and please understand that I am not a native speaker.

I'm trying to create instances of classes during script parses JSON.
Script has dict like:

`classes = {'user': 'User', 'chat': 'Chat', 'message': 'Message'}`

and classes `User`, `Chat`, `Message`. 
When script finds key in json corresponding key in dict I need to create instance of corresponding class.

I found solution, but I think it stupid:

````
>>> class User():
...     name = 'John'
>>> class_name = 'User()'
>>> variable_name = 'user'
>>> exec(f'{variable_name}={class_name}')```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959996/get-python-class-object-from-class-name-string-in-the-same-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `globals()` command as this:

`globals()['user'] = globals()['User']()`

`globals()` function returns you everything you got in your global scope (as `dict`)

Full code:

```py
class User():
    pass
class Chat():
    pass
class Message():
    pass
classes = {'user': 'User', 'chat': 'Chat', 'message': 'Message'}
my_globals = globals()
for var_name, class_name in classes.items():
    my_globals[var_name] = my_globals[class_name]()
```

Comment: Thanks. It works

Comment: @ЕвгенийСоколов no problem :)