# Printing attributes outside of a class getattr Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, for-loop, global

I am trying to print out `result1.key` and `result2.key` by using the `getattr`. However I cannot get the last print function to work. I get the Error: `NameError: name 'key' is not defined`. How would I be able to make the print functions `print(getattr(result1, key)) print(getattr(result2, key))` work to get the Expected Output?

```
results = ["result1", "result2"]
valuelist1 = [3, 5]
valuelist2 = [10, 6]

def func(val, val2):
    return val* val2 + val2/2

class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, val, val2):
        self.key = func(val, val2)

for counter, runs in enumerate(results):
    dummy = Dummy(valuelist1[counter], valuelist2[counter])
    globals()[runs] = dummy


print(result1.key)
print(result2.key)
for name in results:
    print(getattr(name, "key"))
```

Expected output:

```
35.0
33.0
35.0
33.0
```

Comment: You need to put `key` between quotes!

Comment: Sorry i updated the question it was meant to be within a for loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959996/get-python-class-object-from-class-name-string-in-the-same-module

Answer (score 0):

You assign the Dummy instance to the `globals()`. So you need to access them in the same way, because `name` is only the string/name of your variable (in the global scope).

Do

```py
for name in results:
    print(globals()[name].key)
```

or

```py
for name in results:
    print(getattr(globals()[name], "key"))
```

or (but in general I wouldn't recommend to use `eval()`, only mentioned as another possible way for the sake of completeness)

```py
for name in results:
    print(eval(name).key)
```