# How to get class from other module by name

Tags: python

I would like to get a class from another module by its name as string, with the following structure:

```
> foldera
  > folderb1
    > folderc
      - __init__.py
      - folderc.py (parent)
      - folderc_childa.py (child)
      - ....py (more child implementations)
  > folderb2
      - __init__.py
      - converter.py
      - ....py
```

And would like to `getattr` of module `folderc` to list all classes of its files (e.g. a list containing classes named FolderC, FolderCChildA, and so on)

Currently `getattr(foldera.folderb1.folderc, 'FolderCChildA')` displays that it was not found. Because in the debugger `foldera.folderb1.folderc` contains no more classes as attributes than `folderc.py`

I tried things like this [How to get class object from class name string in the same module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959996/how-to-get-class-object-from-class-name-string-in-the-same-module) but it still is not working. Has anyone any advice where my mistake was made?

Solved: solution import classes into init.py of the module

Comment: are you able to import these classes normally using `import`?

Comment: Yes, I can import and use classes FolderCChildA, FolderCChildB, ... in my converter.py

Comment: use `__all__` in  `__init__.py` and add all classes to it. ie `__all__ = ['class1', 'class2']`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but is there a way without manually adding the classes to a list, to get them by name?

Comment: When you manually import the classs, where do you import `FolderCChildA` from? Do you import it in `foldera.folderb1.folderc.__init__.py` so that you can import it from `foldera.folderb1.folderc` or do you import it from `foldera.folderb1.folderc.folderc_childa`?